# Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

Tags: java

I need to know how to fix these error notes:

```
Note: Summer.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.*;

class Summer
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Date d1 = new Date();
        Date j21 = new Date(d1.getYear(), 6, 21);
        if(d1.before(j21)) {
            long diff = j21.getTime() - d1.getTime();
            diff = diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
            System.out.println("There are " + diff + " days until June 21st" );
        }
        else {
            long diff = d1.getTime() - j21.getTime();
            diff = diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
            diff = 365 - diff;
            System.out.println("There are " + diff + " days until June 21st" );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

This is not an error; it's a warning message.

Your program would run as you wrote it.

The reason why the compiler is giving you this warning is because you have used a deprecated function call.

By "recompile with -Xlint", the compiler means to inform you that you need to recompile your program like this:

```
javac -Xlint abc.java
```

If you do so, the compiler will tell you which methods are deprecated so you can remove your calls to them. (If some method is deprecated, it *usually* means that a better implementation is available and that you should use that instead of the deprecated method.)

Answer (score 7):

It's a warning.  You're using a deprecated function call or object.  You can recompile like so to find out where it's occurring:

```
javac -Xlint:deprecation Summer.java
```

Generally, it's a bad idea to use deprecated libraries.  They may go away in the next release.

Comment: Gives some warning message , But run the program correctly . Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As the message says, you need to compile it with `-Xlint` command line switch to the `javac` command as follows:

```
C:\Temp>javac -Xlint Summer.java
Summer.java:22: warning: [deprecation] getYear() in java.util.Date has been deprecated
        Date j21 = new Date(d1.getYear(), 6, 21);
                          ^
Summer.java:22: warning: [deprecation] Date(int,int,int) in java.util.Date has been deprecated
        Date j21 = new Date(d1.getYear(), 6, 21);
               ^
2 warnings
```

Comment: How are you compiling your code, from command line or from the jGrasp development environment?

Comment: I open a new java in jGrasp and start working my code in there. Then I hit the compile file button to check for errors.

Comment: Not sure how you would enable `deprecation` warnings in jGrasp. You may need to look into the jGrasp manual for this. If it was eclipse, you would go to Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings -> Deprecated and restricted API and set the severity level to warning / error.

Comment: Ok, the program seems to work fine as is for now except the fact that it tells me there are 301 days until June 21st when there are not, do you happen to know where I went wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

{Header
....
"scope": [
"pipeline:20": "read",
"job:103": "write"
]
}'TARGET' is not recognized as an internal or external command## Heading ##

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
Note: filename.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

for this ERROR. but its actually a warning for missing the try{}catch(){} block
you can use to see the effected code by writing the following statement

```
javac -Xlint:unchecked filename.java
```

> it will show the unchecked all exceptions that must catch through the user define or system define exception code

Answer (score -2):

Those are not errors. Just warnings. Those will not affect your program. But as you are using deprecated util class Date in future it may affect your program.

It is better to use `java.util.Calendar`  instead of `java.util.Date` this provides same functionality as Date and someextra functionalities also