# Uses or overrides a deprecated API

Tags: java, swing, awt

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class JBall extends JFrame{
JBallPanel news=new JBallPanel();
public JBall(){

super("JBall");
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(420,220);
 JPanel pane=new JPanel();
 pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1,15,15));
  pane.add(news);
  setContentPane(pane);
show();
news.scroll();
}
public static void main(String arg[]){
JBall head=new JBall();
}
}
class JBallPanel extends JPanel{
 String[] headlines={"hello","how are you?"};
int y=76;
void scroll(){
while(true){
y=y-1;
if(y<-7)
y=76;
repaint();
try{
Thread.sleep(250);
}catch(InterruptedException e){}
}
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics comp){
Graphics2D comp2D=(Graphics2D)comp;
comp.setColor(getBackground());
comp.fillRect(0,0,getSize().width,getSize().height);
comp2D.setColor(Color.blue);
for(int i=0;i<headlines.length;i++)
comp2D.drawString(headlines[i],5,y+(20*i));
}
}
```

When I run the above code it says that JBall.java uses or overrides a deprecated API and to recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details . Please help me to figure out where I went wrong.Thanks

Comment: "recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558231/recompile-with-xlintdeprecation-for-details)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`show();` is depcricated use `setVisible(true)` to view.

Following is the description of java docs.

> **Deprecated.** As of JDK version 1.5, replaced by setVisible(boolean).
>
> Makes the Window visible. If the Window and/or its owner are not yet
>   displayable, both are made displayable. The Window will be validated
>   prior to being made visible. If the Window is already visible, this
>   will bring the Window to the front.

Answer (score 0):

The `show()` function is deprecated; replace it with `setVisible(true)`.

Just for understanding: Using something which is deprecated should still work in most cases, the people who wrote that code just recommend that you don't. The idea here is that often one piece of code should be replaced but compatibility shouldn't be broken; therefore the old functions are marked as deprecated with the `@Deprecated` annotation and, if it's done properly, there will be a description on what to use instead from now on. In future versions of that software a function marked as deprecated may be removed.

Comment: You're welcome. Reading the error codes helps a lot and many IDEs will mark the code fragments specified in the error codes.