# error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Trees

Tags: java, linked-list, removeclass

I have three methods. One reads from a file and adds each line to a list as an object. Another asks for a line and removes it. This part is good.

However this is for an assignment it asks to print the line being removed. This is where I am having a bit of trouble. Right now in my method to remove a line I have this:

```
Trees objToRemove = list.get(number);
System.out.println("Removing: " + objToRemove);
```

In which I am trying to get an object from the list at the specified location (number).

I get this error

> incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Trees.

Trees is,

```
Trees tree = new Trees (name, height, diameter);
```

Located in the first method mentioned.

My question is how can I access the object if it is defined in another method? Also, what am I currently doing wrong?

**Edit:** Changed to

```
  Trees objToRemove = (Trees) list.get(number);
```

and it works!

Thank You.

Comment: Is Your List is a Type-Safe `ArrayList` ?? If It is so then only `get(int index)` will give you `Trees` Object Otherwise you should `typecast` the object like `Trees objToRemove  =(Trees) list.get(number)`

Comment: I don't know what type of objects are in your list. Try a quick test: Object obj = list.get(number); System.out.println("classType: " + obj.getClass().getName(); I hope this gives you Tree. Then you can cast obj  to Tree as Vikrant Kashyap suggests. You can also try boolean isTree = obj instanceof Tree;

Comment: @VikrantKashyap how do I know if my list is a Type-Safe LinkedList?

Comment: @flobacca I do get Trees

Answer (score 2):

> Your `ArrayList` Class is Not Type-Safe. So, by Default `get(int index)` will give you a object of `Object` Class.

```
Trees objToRemove = (Trees) list.get(number); //try this
```

instead Of

```
 Trees objToRemove = (Trees) list.get(number);
```

OR Change Your `list` Object as a Type-Safe such that Other type of element could not be added to the `List`.

```
List<Trees> list = new ArrayList<Trees>(); // now no type Casting Needed.
 Trees objToRemove = list.get(number); // This code will Work Fine if You use a Type-Safe ArrayList.
```

There are various Others Reasons Check out Here [Why Use Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html)

Comment: Sorry, didn't specify by list I meant Linked List. I was wondering why I got **Note: Class.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.** when  I compiled. 
My list object is ListInterface<Trees> list = new LinkedList<Trees>();
why is it not safe?

Comment: try this  might helps You >>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558231/recompile-with-xlintdeprecation-for-details

Comment: Is 'ListInterface' another interface, as in you made an interface named 'ListInterface'? Or do you mean to point out that List<Trees> is type of interface?

Comment: Well, I hope someone corrects me if I'm wrong, but List<Trees> list = new LinkedList<Trees>() shouldn't give you any warnings. This is safe to do. What isn't safe is List<Trees> = new LinkedList(); Your linked list on the right is raw, and you're assigning it to a generic List as in it has brackets. It doesn't really matter that you're assigning a LinkedList to a List, but it does matter that you are assigning a raw collection to a generic collection.

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate your List, instead of:

```
List list = new ArrayList<Trees>();
```

Place the type on the other side like so:

```
List<Trees> list = new ArrayList();
```

First way returns an `Object`, second returns the specific type

Answer (score 0):

```
Trees objToRemove = list.get(number);
```

You are assigning the object to your Trees class which is incompatible. You need to cast it.

```
Trees objToRemove = (Trees) list.get(number);
```