# When i compile my program iam getting Error-SampleApplet.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. And Recompile with -xlint:deprecation for details

Tags: java

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class SampleApplet extends Applet
{
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.drawOval(10,10,100,100);
        g.fillOval(120,10,100,100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably because you're using a deprecated API. Doesn't your IDE / compiler tell you what line the error is on? That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: dave-how can i remove this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558231/recompile-with-xlintdeprecation-for-details)

Comment: If you're using Java 9 or higher, please note that the _entire_ Applet API has been [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Deprecated.html); Java applets are obsolete.